# Add two MP3 files to an MP4 file using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I am using ffmpeg on Windows and getting the following error as I try to add two MP3

```
Stream specifier '' in filtergraph description [1]adelay=1|1[b];[2]adelay=100|100[c];[0][b][c]amix=3 matches no streams.
```

using the following command

```
ffmpeg -i vidwithnoaudio.mp4 -i audio0.mp3 -i audio1.mp3 -filter_complex "[1]adelay=1|1[b];[2]adelay=100|100[c];[0][b][c]amix=3" vidwithaudio.mp4
```

Here is an alternative command I have found I am trying to edit into working with this:

```
ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -i 1.3gp -i 2.3gp -i 1.mp3
  -filter_complex "[2]adelay=10000|10000[s2];[3:a][1:a][s2]amix=3[a]"
  -map 0:v -map "[a]" -c:v copy result.mp4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`vidwithnoaudio.mp4` has no audio, but you are telling amix to use the non-existent audio from `vidwithnoaudio.mp4` as an input. Use:

```
ffmpeg -i vidwithnoaudio.mp4 -i audio0.mp3 -i audio1.mp3 -filter_complex "[1]adelay=1|1[b];[2]adelay=100|100[c];[b][c]amix=inputs=2[a]" -map 0:v -map "[a]" -c:v copy -shortest vidwithaudio.mp4
```